# Ubuntu 18.04 - On Screen Keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard

no, this is not a duplicate. I'm having trouble disabling the on screen keyboard.

I do not have caribou nor onboard installed.

i tried anyway the shell extension block caribou and the other one but no success

i tried the command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled false`

and yet no success.

Is there any clue on how to remove this thing ?

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with a touch screen

### EDIT - PS -Af

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 ago13 ?        00:00:10 /sbin/init splash
root         2     0  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root         6     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H-kb]
root         8     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         9     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:08 [ksoftirqd/0]
root        10     2  0 ago13 ?        00:05:31 [rcu_sched]
root        11     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:01 [migration/0]
root        12     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/0]
root        14     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        15     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/1]
root        16     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/1]
root        17     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:01 [migration/1]
root        18     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:07 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        21     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/2]
root        22     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/2]
root        23     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:01 [migration/2]
root        24     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:04 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        26     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H-kb]
root        27     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/3]
root        28     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/3]
root        29     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:01 [migration/3]
root        30     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:03 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        32     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:05 [kworker/3:0H-ev]
root        33     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        34     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        35     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_tasks_kthre]
root        36     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root        37     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        38     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [oom_reaper]
root        39     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
root        40     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kcompactd0]
root        41     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root        42     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [khugepaged]
root        90     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
root        91     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root        92     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [blkcg_punt_bio]
root        94     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [tpm_dev_wq]
root        95     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
root        96     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [md]
root        97     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [edac-poller]
root        98     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        99     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [watchdogd]
root       102     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root       103     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root       105     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root       106     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root       107     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       108     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root       109     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       110     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root       112     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       113     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root       114     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       115     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_3]
root       118     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [vfio-irqfd-clea]
root       120     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root       129     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kstrp]
root       132     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u9:0]
root       146     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [charger_manager]
root       195     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root       196     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_4]
root       199     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root       200     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_5]
root       203     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:09 [kworker/2:1H-ev]
root       223     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:02 [kworker/3:1H-ev]
root       225     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:10 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       226     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       276     1  0 ago13 ?        00:02:46 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       286     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
systemd+   369     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:43 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+   371     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root       381     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [irq/30-mei_me]
root       417     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:22 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
root       418     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root       419     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root       420     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root       426     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root       428     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:08 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root       473     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:07 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
root       474     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:08 /usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable
root       475     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ModemManager --filter-policy=strict
syslog     476     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:37 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
message+   477     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
root       525     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [cryptd]
root       607     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
root       608     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       617     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root       657     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:34 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
root       684     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       749     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:07 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root       798   607  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/dhclient-enp1s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-4b44fdca-2aa4-32ba-83f8-a221df2a07f2-enp1s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp1s0.conf enp1s0
whoopsie   928     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/whoopsie -f
kernoops   931     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/kerneloops --test
kernoops   934     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/kerneloops
root       949     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/gdm3
root       959   949  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-autologin]
leo        963     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
leo        964   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
leo        986     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
leo        990   959  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
leo        992   990  0 ago13 tty1     00:05:41 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
leo       1022   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
leo       1025   990  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
leo       1135  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:01:07 /usr/bin/unclutter -idle 1 -root
leo       1149  1025  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
leo       1206   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
leo       1238   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
leo       1252   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
leo       1257  1252  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
leo       1260   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
leo       1345   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground --components=secrets
leo       1385  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:15:19 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
root      1388     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop0]
root      1396     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
leo       1476     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
rtkit     1477     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
leo       1492  1385  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
leo       1494   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
leo       1502  1492  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf
leo       1504     1  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
leo       1506   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-portal
leo       1517   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server
leo       1521   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
leo       1528   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
root      1535     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/boltd
leo       1542   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:06 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
leo       1546   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
leo       1551   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
leo       1555   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
leo       1559   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
root      1563     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:14 /usr/lib/packagekit/packagekitd
leo       1565  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-power
leo       1567  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-print-notifications
leo       1571  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill
leo       1572  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sharing
leo       1584  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-smartcard
leo       1588  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
leo       1592  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-wacom
leo       1593  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sound
leo       1598  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-clipboard
leo       1601  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-a11y-settings
leo       1604  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-datetime
leo       1606  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:46 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color
leo       1609  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
leo       1610  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:03 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-housekeeping
leo       1615  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-mouse
leo       1632     1  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
colord    1659     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/colord/colord
leo       1666   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
leo       1672  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gsd-disk-utility-notify
root      1691     1  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 dbus-launch --autolaunch=08f1669ef374475fb4fb565dfa5253f7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr
root      1694     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog-only --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
root      1698     1  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
leo       1757  1206  0 ago13 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.7 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
leo       1851  1492  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
leo       1856  1666  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory all --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx1666x2 --own-path /org/gnome/evolution/dataserver/Subprocess/Backend/Calendar/1666/2
leo       1906   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory
leo       1932  1906  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess --factory all --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.AddressBookx1906x2 --own-path /org/gnome/evolution/dataserver/Subprocess/Backend/AddressBook/1906/2
leo       1940   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
leo       1991     1  0 ago13 tty1     00:02:30 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --enable-pinch --disable --nocursor --disable-translate --disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-translate --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --password-store=basic --disable-suggestions-service --disable-save-password-bubble --disk-cache-dir=/home/leo/tmp/chromium/cache/ --start-maximized --kiosk http://localhost/Bartop_Game_Manager/index.php
leo       1999  1991  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote --no-zygote-sandbox
leo       2000  1991  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote
leo       2002  2000  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote
leo       2022  1999 38 ago13 tty1     1-00:58:29 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=17921951543535052098,17985232017626574708,131072 --gpu-preferences=UAAAAAAAAAAgAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files
leo       2027  1991  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:04 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --field-trial-handle=17921951543535052098,17985232017626574708,131072 --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=none --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
leo       2046  2002  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=utility --utility-sub-type=storage.mojom.StorageService --field-trial-handle=17921951543535052098,17985232017626574708,131072 --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=utility --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
leo       2063  2002  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=17921951543535052098,17985232017626574708,131072 --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=6 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
leo       2064  2002 68 ago13 tty1     1-20:39:08 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=17921951543535052098,17985232017626574708,131072 --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=5 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
root      2411     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop1]
root      2548     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop2]
root      2659     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop3]
root      2757     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop4]
root      2889     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop5]
root      3010     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop6]
root      3157     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop7]
leo       3213  1025  0 ago13 tty1     00:00:09 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
root      3530     2  0 ago15 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root      6148     2  0 09:39 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:2-eve]
leo       9222   963  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
leo       9231  9222  0 ago13 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root     10567     2  0 10:00 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:2-cgr]
root     12370     2  0 10:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1-cgr]
www-data 15117   749  0 00:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15118   749  0 00:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15119   749  0 00:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15120   749  0 00:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15121   749  0 00:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     15291     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop8]
root     15360     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop9]
root     15398     1  0 ago13 ?        00:01:08 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
root     15753     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop10]
root     15760     2  0 10:25 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:3-eve]
root     15761     2  0 10:25 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:4]
root     15774     2  0 10:25 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:3-eve]
root     16010     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop11]
root     16061     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop12]
root     16130     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop13]
root     16213     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop14]
root     16264     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop15]
root     16400     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop16]
root     16827     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:00 [loop17]
root     16989     2  0 ago13 ?        00:01:05 [kworker/0:2H-kb]
root     17076     2  0 10:32 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:1-ev]
root     17158     2  0 ago13 ?        00:00:03 [kworker/1:2H-ev]
root     19128     2  0 00:25 ?        00:00:02 [kworker/1:0-eve]
root     20153     2  0 10:46 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1-eve]
root     20199     2  0 10:46 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:3-ev]
root     20256   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20257   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20258   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20259   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20260   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20261   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20262   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20263   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20264   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20265   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20266   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     20267   428  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
leo      20268 20256  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 60; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20269 20267  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 5; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20270 20257  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 55; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20271 20264  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 20; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20272 20271  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 20
leo      20273 20261  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 35; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20274 20262  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 30; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20275 20266  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 10; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20276 20265  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 15; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20277 20275  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 10
leo      20278 20258  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 50; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20279 20269  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 5
leo      20280 20273  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 35
leo      20281 20274  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 30
leo      20282 20270  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 55
leo      20283 20276  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 15
leo      20284 20268  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 60
leo      20285 20278  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 50
leo      20286 20263  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 25; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20287 20286  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 25
leo      20288 20260  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 40; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20289 20259  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 45; php /var/www/html/bin/beat.php
leo      20290 20289  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 45
leo      20291 20288  0 10:47 ?        00:00:00 sleep 40
leo      20292  9231  0 10:47 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -Af
root     21024     2  0 08:16 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:2-ev]
www-data 21904   749  0 00:39 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     24279     2  0 08:32 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:0-ev]
root     26892     2  0 08:44 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0-eve]
```

Comment: When the on screen keyboard is activated, can you try to identify the process to tell what program it is, for example `ps -Af | less` or if you still suspect onboard or caribou `ps -Af | grep -i -e 'onboard' -e 'caribou'` - Anyway, a brutal way is to uninstall the naughty program. The deb packages (used by apt) have the same names as the two programs (onboard and caribou).

Comment: hi @sudodus 

i did the ps but i honestly can't find anything keyboard related. updating my question with the output of ps -Af

Comment: Is it possible that the keyboard you see is hardcoded into the computer (not part of the Ubuntu operating system)? I don't know. Maybe someone who knows better can find the process that is responsible for the on screen keyboard, by reading the output of the ps command..

Comment: i dont think is possible, this is litterally the ubuntu osk

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed? In that case what happens when you run Ubuntu **live** booted from a USB drive? If the onscreen keyboard is there too, what happens when you run **Lubuntu** live booted from a USB drive? (I am asking this, because the on scrren keyboard might be 'hidden' in gnome, and Lubuntu does not use gnome).

Comment: ubuntu is fully installed. if you want i try with lubuntu too

Comment: If your internet has good bandwidth, it should be fast to download a current Lubuntu iso file, clone it to a USB pendrive and boot from it :-P

Comment: so basically you are telling me that is easier to use another linux distro then unistall the ubuntu osk ? (for me is ok)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128613/discussion-between-sudodus-and-antonio-dangeo).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

somehow....i solved by messing up the permissions in the .config folder (/home/user/.config)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on your answer? As it stands there is not much specific information there that might help future readers. Also I have removed the mildly shielded expletive from your answer...

Comment: Hi @andrew.46, i really don't know about how to elaborate more. I stumbled on this by pure accident. i gave root ownership to that folder by mistake, and the osk stopd showing up. So, a mistake lead to a solution.